# Drupal - magnific popup only works when logged in

Tags: drupal-7, magnific-popup

I am using magnific popup JS (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to produce a popup for a youtube video on my Drupal site. The implementation works fine, but only if I am logged into Drupal. If I am not logged in, the popup link will just go the the youtube page (eg jQuery not initialising).

I suspect there may be something going on with Drupal loading a different version of jQuery when I am logged in. It seems that I may be able to add something to my template file to fix this. Haven't figured it out yet (https://www.drupal.org/node/2165555)

I do not have access to add jQuery update module.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Added below snippet to template.php to force a later version of jQuery to load.

```
function theme_name_js_alter(&$javascript) {
 $node_admin_paths = array(
 'node/*/edit',
 'node/add',
 'node/add/*',
 'node/*/extend_review_date',
 );
$replace_jquery = TRUE;
if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
 $replace_jquery = FALSE;
 } else {
  foreach ($node_admin_paths as $node_admin_path) {
    if (drupal_match_path(current_path(), $node_admin_path)) {
    $replace_jquery = FALSE;
   }
 }
 }
 // Swap out jQuery to use an updated version of the library.
 if ($replace_jquery) {
 $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js';
}
}
```